# Timer isn't working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Guys I am trying to run ProgressBar using DispatcherTimer. I created an event "Timer_Tick" and changing the value of progressbar. But it isn't working. I am new to WPF so plss help me with this problem. :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int counter = 1;
        public event EventHandler OnFormLoading;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OnFormLoading += MainWindow_OnFormLoading;

        }

        void MainWindow_OnFormLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            timer.Start();

        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            progressBar1.Value += counter;

            if (counter == 10) timer.Stop();

            counter++;
        }

        private void Form1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            OnFormLoading(this, new EventArgs());

        }
    }
}
```

XAML CODE:

```
<Window x:Name="Form1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Form1_Loaded">
    <Grid Background="#FF070B34">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="395*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="298*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="99*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="308*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="261*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Height="41" Margin="190,31,93.015,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="#FF4C5FD8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF8A83D3" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </TextBlock.Effect><Run Language="en-gb" Text="WELCOME TO E-VOTING MACHINE"/></TextBlock>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Hussam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\bin\Debug\emachine.jpg" Margin="64,0,64,87" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="393" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Value="0" Minimum="0" Height="27" Margin="140,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: ProgressBar should change its value with timer's ticking but its not changing the value. ProgressBar isn't running.

Comment: See my answer below, dispatch timer is part of System.Threading assembly. it will be executing the timer tick at the end of dispatcher queue, not at given period. Therefore you may not get the timer tick until the dispatcher queue gets priority. Also UI update should be in main thread, not in the timer thread.

Comment: Post your XAML as well. If you missed to wire up Loaded event on the Window, nothing would work, as you are starting everything from Form1_Loded method.

Comment: dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);

Comment: @Blam That makes no difference.

Comment: Are you debugging?  Do you see event called?

Comment: Thanks for ur help guys... Its working on the other overloaded constructor of TimeSpan. I don't know why but its working.

Comment: @Hussam_7102 Which constructor are you using now?

Comment: First of all your are mixing WPF with Windows Form. Not a good idea. You should get rid of the reference to Windows Form assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Read this MSDN article, it explains everything you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx

It is best you use System.Timer.Timer instead of dispatch timer. Also the timer runs on different thread therefore the UI update must be done via delegate.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private int count = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _timer = new Timer(1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(UpdateProgressBar);
        }

        private void UpdateProgressBar()
        {
            progressBar1.Value = count;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. I'm able to run it just fine on my machine.
It ticks every 10 secs. I don't know why it doesn't work on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, Its working on the other overloaded constructor of TimeSpan. I don't know why but its working.

Answer (score 0):

You need Dispatcher and i think new versions of .net have DispatcherTimer class also. When you updating the main thread from other, you need to do it via dispatcher.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58836/Using-Background-Process-in-WPF

Answer (score -2):

try put following statementa at the end of timer_tick function

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```